# sqlite python script - fetchall: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, sqlite, nonetype

I created the method update_instance, but when I call it I keep getting the error  object of type 'NoneType' has no len(), the intention is to update the the instance attributes only if len(BREG_TRADE_GOING rows ) > 0, thank you in advance for your help

```
def update_instance(self):
        #db = self.file_path
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.file_path)
        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute("SELECT * FROM BREG_TRADE_GOING")
        rows = c.fetchall()
        print(rows)
        print (len(rows))
        if len(rows) > 0:
            try:
                for row in rows:
                    if row[1] in StockData.symbol_list:
                        symbol = row[1]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].target_order_id = row[0]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].symbol = row[1]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].min_quantity = row[2]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].min_price = row[3]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].asset = row[4]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].crossover_type = row[5]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].trade_type = row[6]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].trade_price = row[7]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].entry_time = row[8]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].entry_trade_amount = row[9]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].buy_order_id = row[10]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].sell_amount = row[11]
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].trade_going = True
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].buy_order_filled = True
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].target_order_placed = True
                        StockData.symbol_instance_dict[symbol].exit_time = row[15]
                        StockData.open_positions.append(symbol)
            except sqlite3.Error as e:
                self.log.error("Database error: %s" % e)
            except Exception as e:
                self.log.error("Exception in _query: %s" % e)
            finally:
                if conn:
                    conn.close()
```

traceback:

```
[(17814868, 'symbol', 1.0, 2.9e-07, 'BTC', 'positive', 'buy', 2.93e-06, '23/10/2018 12:46:38', 717.0, 17814857, 716.0, 1, 1, 1, None), (25999559, 'symbol', 1.0, 2.519e-05, 'BTC', 'positive', 'buy', 0.00025567, '23/10/2018 13:02:52', 8.0, 25999466, 8.0, 1, 1, 1, None), (31585121, 'symbol', 1.0, 2e-07, 'BTC', 'positive', 'buy', 1.92e-06, '23/10/2018 16:32:01', 1094.0, 31585118, 1093.0, 1, 1, 1, None)]
3
Started...
web socket started...
object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting from print(rows)?

Comment: i get the rows[(somedata),(somedata),(somedata)] and the len=3

Comment: Please show the full traceback. The error doesn't make sense. `fetchone()` can give `None` but not `fetchall`

Comment: But the error flags in the `print (len(rows))` line right?

Comment: I try the new statement if rows: but same problem, and message: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: I removed that comment realizing it wouldn't work. Like the others have stated, the error doesn't make sense. I think it's from somewhere else within your code.

Comment: ok, I will have to debug it, but what is very interesting is that the code will run fine if I dont call this method, as soon as I call the method mentioned, the error pops up.

Comment: Right, this is more complex because you don't have all the traceback data. Try wrapping in a `try`/`except`, import `traceback` and `print(traceback.format_exc())` on exception to see if you get the stack trace.

Comment: @roganjosh I am not using fethone() in the entire script, I will wrap it now ...

Comment: @b-fg the script will print len()

Comment: Right, so we're still trying to establish what is causing this

Comment: Is the error caused by the 'None' values within your list? Perhaps you could try manually creating a list, and copy that output but remove the None values and pass the custom list instead. This would tell you if that's the issue or not.

Comment: @BriceFrisco I see your point in the rows the last value is 'None'... let try for a workaround

Comment: @roganjosh i tried to wrap it ... please see the questions re-edit... but not error reported

Comment: That isn't what I suggested, I showed you how to catch the traceback using the `traceback` module. We're not moving forwards here unless you can access this data.

Comment: Thank you all for your help... after debugging I have found the source of the problem, as many of you suggested it was ... in another method, that was being collaterally affected by the method I posted.